# How to build Linux kernel to support SO_ATTACH_BPF socket option?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I want to build a application which supports `eBPF` on `CentOS 7` (the kernel version is `3.10.0`):

```
if(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_BPF, prog_fd, sizeof(prog_f)) {
    ......
}
```

So I download a `4.0.5` version, make the following configurations on:

```
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
```

Then follow this [link](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) to build and install a `4.0.5` kernel.

After executing `make modules_install install`, I find there is still no `SO_ATTACH_BPF` in `<asm-generic/socket.h>`, so the above code can't be compiled successfully.

How to build Linux kernel to support `SO_ATTACH_BPF` socket option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my setup, which is based on Fedora 21, I use very similar steps to those you linked to compile and install the latest kernel. As an additional step, I will do the following from the kernel build tree to install the kernel header files into /usr/local/include:

```
sudo make INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr/local headers_install
```

This will cause both the stock kernel header files to remain installed in `/usr/include/{linux,asm,asm-generic,...}`, and the new kernel header files to be installed in `/usr/local/include/{linux,asm,asm-generic,...}`. During your test program compile, depending on which build system you use, you may need to prefix gcc/clang with `-I/usr/local/include`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it posible to replace the whole older kernel header files with the newer kernel completely? I use `make headers_install` command, the output is "CHK   include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  INSTALL usr/include/linux/ (411 files) ". It install all the files in `/usr/include/linux` directory.

Comment: You can use /usr as the argument to INSTALL_HDR_PATH. The better explanation for how to use headers_install is here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/headers_install.txt. However, I believe the example of "/usr/include" is wrong, as in my experiments this created /usr/include/include.

Comment: However, please be aware that there are conflicting answers to this, and some have reported issues when using /usr as the argument. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/make-headers_install-deleted-header-files-944363/

Answer (score 0):

Your newly installed kernel supports `SO_ATTACH_BPF`, but your current `libc` package doesn't now about that (as you mention, distro's native 3.10.0 kernel lacks of given option support).

You need to update `libc` package as well for use new kernel's features in user space programs.

Comment: `<asm-generic/socket.h>` is in `libc`? not kernel header files?

Comment: `libc` has **own copy** of include files, shared between kernel and user. In the kernel such files are placed under `include/uapi/` and `arch/<arch>/include/uapi/`.

Comment: My `libc` version is `2.17`. How do I know which `libc` supports  `SO_ATTACH_BPF`?

Comment: Current `glibc`, which is used by the most Linux distros, seems has no support for that option (see repo http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git). You can try `libc` from other vendors. E.g., this one https://gitlab.com/bminor/musl/tree/70572dce07a631e2f818b34f5679c57eeebc9779 has support for the option you need.